# Get items older than two months

Tags: mysql

I have a list of helpdesk calls, and I'm trying to create a list of old calls i.e. where we haven't heard from them for more than 2 months.

I was trying to do something along the lines of the following:

```
select company, closedate 
from opencall 
where closedate < date sub (curdate(), interval 60 day) 
group by company
```

but this doesn't work.

How do I return a result set of companies we haven't heard from for 2 months or more?

Comment: that didnt seem to update as i expected. the sql query i wrote was as follows select company,closedate from opencall where closedate>=date_sub (curdate(),interval 60 day) group by company

Comment: the above result set seems to return everything not just items older than 60 days. ideally id like to create a report that lets us know a list of clients who havent contacted us for x amount of days. We can then contact them accordingly.

Comment: I've tried to fix the formatting of your code by putting it in a code block - as you pointed out it wasn't displaying properly.

Comment: Surely closedate >= date_sub (curdate(),interval 60 day) gives you all things since 2 moths back, not before? surely you'd want  closedate <= date_sub (curdate(),interval 60 day)

Comment: @bugfinder thankyou for your comments ive tried select companyname,closedate from opencall where closedate <=date_sub(curdate(),interval 60 day) but it still returns all data, even some from this month?? my date field im date_sub'ing on is "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" would that make any difference?

Comment: @bridge thank you im new to forums, so my post hadnt quite come out as i expected it to. I will know for next time!

Comment: can you do a date_sub (curdate() - 60 day) ive tried this and this too doesnt seem to work. Im not sure if its the syntax that isnt working, or incorrect syntax?

Comment: try something more simple..
select company, closedate, date_sub(curdate(),interval 60 day) from opencall and see what values you're getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

**(edited example)**

```
CREATE TABLE opencall(
  company INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  closedate DATE DEFAULT NULL
);

-- Populate table, only company=4 has old reecords.
INSERT INTO opencall VALUES 
  (1, '2012-09-18'),
  (1, '2012-06-05'),
  (1, '2012-08-18'),
  (2, '2012-09-13'),
  (2, '2012-08-04'),
  (4, '2012-05-12'),
  (4, '2012-04-11');

SELECT t1.company, t1.closedate FROM opencall t1
  JOIN (SELECT company, MAX(closedate) max_closedate
       FROM opencall
       GROUP BY company
       HAVING max_closedate < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY
       ) t2
    ON t1.company = t2.company;

+---------+------------+
| company | closedate  |
+---------+------------+
|       4 | 2012-05-12 |
|       4 | 2012-04-11 |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: thanks for the pointers, but there are no joins, both closedate and company come from the opencall table. I have tried your suggestion and get the following "standard" error "you have an error in your sql syntax" this query is being run on a mysql database. Thank you

Comment: Where are no joins? It does work in MySQL. Don't you use view by the way?

Comment: im quite new to mysql, so i know there appears to be some differecnes with how the syntax works. But when i ran the command you gave me, it stated "you have an error in your syntax" I w ill give it another try. Whats view?

Comment: OK, I will add full code at my answer. View are objects, in MySQL they do not allow using subqueries; but I see you do not use views. So, have a look at example.

Comment: would it make any difference if my closedate colum contained values of "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: If `closedate` is a string type, then you should convert it to DATE or DATETIME type. If it is DATE or DATETIME then query has to work. Show your CREATE TABLE.

Comment: i also have an epoch date colum if this is easier to use i.e. closedatex

Comment: i think it would if i had a table setup as per the example but i do not.

Comment: If closedate is not of a DATE data type, change it so that it is!